# Show that $Px=\left \langle x, y \right \rangle z$ defines a compact linear operator on $X$ with fixed vectors $y$, $z$ in $X$

Tags: functional-analysis

My Questions:

Givem $X$ is a Hilbert space with inner product $\left \langle \cdot ,\cdot  \right \rangle$

(1) Show that $Px=\left \langle x, y \right \rangle z$ is a compact linear operator on $X$ with fixed vectors $y$, $z$ in $X$.

(2) Use Riesz representation theorem to show that $Qx=f(x)z$ with fixed $z\in X$ and $f\in X'$ is a compact operator on $X$.

---

My Trial:

(1) By definition of **compact operator**, it means that every bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ implies $Px$ has a convergent subsequence.

Then, I consider $Px_n=\left \langle x_n, y \right \rangle z$ but I do now know how to prove that this stuff has convergent subsequence.

I have seen some exercises that it suffices to prove the sequence $Px_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Should I do this?

(2) By Riesz representation theorem, I know that if $T \in L(X, F)$, then there exists a unique $x_0\in X$ such that $\forall x\in X$, $Tx=\left \langle x, x_0 \right \rangle$.

I do not understand the question by the notation $f(x)z$. How do this related to Riesz representation theorem.

(3) Thanks in advance with providing steps as I am quite new to this topic.

Comment: For the first part, it is sufficient to show that $P$ is a finite rank operator. All finite rank operators are compact.

Comment: @Cameron Can I write this: $range(P)\subset$ span$(z)$ and span$(z)$ is finite-dimensional, then it turns out that $P$ is compact.

Comment: Since $P$ is bounded, the sequence $( (x_n,y))$ is a bounded set of scalars. It has a convergent subsequence. Thus, so does $(Px_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, it is sufficient to show that $P$ is a finite rank operator. All finite rank operators (in any Banach space, not just Hilbert space) are compact operators so this does the job.

For the second part, the Riesz representation theorem says that if $f\in X^*$, then $f(x) = \langle y,x\rangle$ for some fixed $y\in X^* \cong X$. This then reduces to the first example because $f(x)z$ would then be equal to $\langle y, x\rangle z$ which is precisely what the first part was about.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the meaning of the questions now. Would you please also tell me that if what I say in the comment is correct or not?

Comment: It is correct. :)